# Integral curves of vector fields on closed surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields

If we have a vector field on a boundary less and compact 2-manifold,  which is neither a gradient nor a harmonic, does that imply its integral curves are closed?

Comment: No. Take straight lines of irrational slope on a torus.

Comment: If you are parametrizing the straight lines as (t,ct) (with appropriate modulus operations), then these are integral curves of a harmonic. I am interested in vector fields which are not harmonics.  Can you think of a different parametrization whose tangent field is actually continuous (and  therefore a vector filed)?

Comment: @Eracnet: Out of after-the-fact curiosity, did you mean "_all_ integral curves are closed" (as your question wording suggests) or "_there exists_ a closed integral curve"? The only compact surfaces foliated by circles are the torus and Klein bottle, so if you mean "all", then your question has a negative answer for rather blunt topological reasons. (Of course, Amitai's post shows the answer is "no" even for the second wording, and the same idea extends the argument to arbitrary surfaces....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T$ be the $2$-torus with the flat metric. Then every vector field of the form$$X=a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial}{\partial y},$$where $a$ and $b$ are constants, is harmonic. By the Hodge decomposition theorem, the space of harmonic vector fields is $2$-dimensional, and hence all the harmonic vector fields have the above form.

Let $f:T\to\mathbb{R}$ be smooth, non-vanishing and non-constant. Define a vector field $X$ by$$X(p)=f(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+cf(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y},$$where $c$ is an irrational constant. Then the trajectories of $X$ are straight lines with irrational slope, hence not closed. Clearly, $X$ is not a gradient, as it does not vanish. By the first paragraph, $X$ is not harmonic.

Comment: That helps... Thanks!